# Mongodb does not update existing record.field

Tags: mongodb, erlang

I am doing an $inc in Mongodb of an existing field of an existing record.
I check getLastError right after the update. It mostly works OK, but sometimes it returns:

{n, 0,
connectionId, 107,
err, null,                                                                                             ok, 1.0}

This means: there was no error, but zero records are updated (n=0).
What I expect it to return: 1 record updated (n=1).
I check the record.field for existance right before the update. And there is no other way for the record.field to disappear.

How can this be?

I use official Erlang driver, but it does not seem to be a driver issue.

The code:

```
change_gold_amount(User, GoldDiff) when is_record(User, user)  ->
    {ok, {Document}} = find_one(users, {'_id', User#user.id}),
    UserGold = bson:lookup(gold, Document, 0),
    case UserGold + GoldDiff < 0 of
        true ->
            {error, not_enough_gold};
        false ->
            {ok, LastErr} = do(fun() ->  mongo:modify(users, 
                                                      {'_id', User#user.id}, 
                                                      {'$inc', {gold, GoldDiff}}),
                                         mongo:command({getlasterror, 1})
                               end),
            case bson:lookup(n, LastErr) of
                {1} -> {ok, User#user{gold=UserGold + GoldDiff}};
                _ -> {error, {mongo_error, LastErr}}
            end
    end.

find_one(Collection, Selector) ->
    do(fun() -> mongo:find_one(Collection, Selector) end).

do(Fun) -> 
    mongo:do(safe, master, get_connection(), ?DB_NAME, Fun).
```

Records of users table have "_id" and "gold" field.

Thanks.

Comment: You're going to need to give some more information such as your document structure, the driver code you run to insert the document, the driver code you use to update the document, etc. before anyone can give suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the update function code sample and comments about data structure. Insertion code, I guess, does not matter, because the update first fetches the record from DB.

Comment: I'd love to help you, but can't find anything wrong with your code.  On the other hand, we don't use getlasterror where I work.  Thank you for teaching me.  How often do you get this error of yours?

Comment: Daniel, getLastError is automatically called by driver after every DB operation in safe mode. And the driver will throw an error if getLastError does not return OK. They only reason I call getLastError explicitly is because I want to know **n** - number of modified records.

Answer (score 0):

I've read the driver code once again, more carefully, and found out that mongo:do function does provide same setup during execution of its Fun argument (connection, safety level, etc), but it does **not** provide exclusive access to connection during the mongo:do call.

If this is true, then I might be getting getLastError for unrelated operations.

Please correct me if I am wrong.